# Using template dependent type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use templates to encode fields in a class - I'm working on a wire protocol - but those templates are giving me a hard time. Basically, I want to be able to specify "Fields" and how they should be encoded for the wire (among other things, I'm simplifying for this question), using templates. Here is my attempt, but I get a compile time error (see below) - is it something I'm not doing correctly for dependent type names?

```
// Encodes values, but identity for this example
template <typename T>
struct Encoder {
  typename T::type operator()(const typename T::type& value) {
    return value;
  }
};

// Declares the properties of Fields (such as Encoding...)
template <typename T, typename E=Encoder<T>>
struct Field {
  typedef T type;
  typedef E encoder;
};

// A root for all classes that need Encoded Fields
struct C {
  template <typename T>
  void set(const typename T::type& value) {
    typename T::encoder encode;
    encode(value);
  }
};

// A mock specific class with 1 Encoded Field
struct H : C {
  typedef Field<int> my_field;
};

int main() {
  H h;
  h.set<H::my_field>(3);
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
 In instantiation of 'struct Encoder<int>': 
   required from 'void C::set(const typename T::type&) [ with T = F<int>; typename T::type = int]'
   required from here
 error: 'int' is not a class, struct or union type
 typename T::type operator()(const typename T::type& value) {
```

Comment: It's telling you that you are trying to instantiate `Encoder<int>`, because `Field<int>` is `Field<int, Encoder<int>>`, but `int` has no member `type` (obviously). I'm not sure what's unclear about the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of your instantiation process, you make an `Encoder<int>`. But `Encoder<T>` has a member function:

```
typename T::type operator()(const typename T::type& value);
```

And you cannot evaluate `int::type`. But based on `C::set()`:

```
template <typename T>                        // T = Field<int>
void set(const typename T::type& value) {    // value is int
    typename T::encoder encode;              // encode is Encoder<int>
    encode(value);        
}
```

You're just passing in the value directly, so the `value` in question is just a `T`. That is, your `Encoder` should be:

```
template <typename T>
struct Encoder {
  T operator()(const T& value) {
    return value;
  }
};
```

Which also makes more semantic sense. An `Encoder` takes a `T` and returns some other `T`. With that change, your code compiles.

Comment: I think you nailed it - I was confused about the types :-(

Answer (score 2):

> is it something I'm not doing correctly for dependent type names?

Yes.

The type used to instantiate `Encoder` is `int`, not `Field<int>`.

Changing `Encoder` to:

```
template <typename T>
struct Encoder {
  T operator()(const T& value) {
    return value;
  }
};
```

works but I am not sure you didn't have something else in mind.

Comment: I think you nailed it - I was confused about the types :-(